# Report - Text Field Less Than number

Tags: reporting, formula-field

I want to create a report for an object that has a text field 'identity__c'.

The text field is usually in the format of a number and I want to run a report with a filter that will return all records with a 'number' less than 1000.

At the moment I have achieved this by creating a number formula field identity_num__c that outputs VALUE(identity__c) and then running a filter on the object identity_num__c  less than 1000.

Is there any way to create this report without having to make a new field on the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to compare two fields is for them to be the same data type. Your approach of using a formula is the only way I know of doing what you're after.